# Unable to make mosh work when ufw is enabled

Tags: ssh, networking, arch-linux, ufw, mosh

I have a RPi running ArchLinux where I can login with `mosh` when `ufw` is disabled, but it doesn't work when it's enabled. This is my `ufw` setup:

```
❯ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 60001/udp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

I've checked with wireshark on PC side (also running ArchLinux) that when `ufw` is disabled, 22 and 60001 are the sole ports being used. When I enable `ufw` I just keep getting TCP retransmissions on port 22.

I also tried `ufw limit ssh/tcp` and `ufw allow mosh`:

```
❯ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     LIMIT IN    Anywhere
[ 2] mosh                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 22/tcp (v6)                LIMIT IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 4] mosh (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Any idea of what's left to fix this?

Comment: retransmissions on port 22: are you saying that ssh itself doesn't work, without even the addition of mosh?

Answer (score 0):

I've rebooted my DHCP server, router and both machines. Everything is working now...